# Java: How do I replace an "oval" or "rectangle" graphic with an imported PNG file?

Tags: java, image, import, replace, png

I imported:

```
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
```

and I used this code to import the PNG file. (i know i can create a black square easily, but it is the importing any image to my game that i want).

```
Image player1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("Users/Documents/JavaGameImages/Tag/BlackSquare.png");
```

I tried to call this image later down, but the image did not appear in the window. (assume myX = 100 and myY = 100)

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {         
        g.setColor(BackgroundColor);
        g.fillRect(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 1000, 1000);
```

/////////////////////// The code below is where i am having trouble:

```
        g.drawImage(player1, myX, myY, null);
```

Comment: That's probably not the correct url for the image.

Comment: There is no run time error. I am certain it is the right location. (I tested in terminal with "tab") and the file is clearly there. I can see it in finder and can be opened without corruption.

Comment: A lack of an exception doesn't mean your code worked, only that it didn't fail spectacularly.

Comment: Ahhh, i see. I tried the code:  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  


     java.io.File file = new         java.io.File("Users/Documents/JavaGameImages/Tag/BlackSquare.png");
if (file.exists())
    System.out.println("The file exists!");
else
    System.out.println("The file does not exist!");


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
And Eclipse said the file doesn't exist, so i have no idea what is going on... any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Should there be an initial slash at the beginning of that file name?

Comment: YES! It worked! thanks so much! -- wow, can't believe i didn't see that. :D thank you!!

Comment: I'd recommend [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) for loading images, IMHO. Check [here for examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: If the image is to be embedded within your final application, your going to need to use geClass().getResource(...) to locate it

Answer (score 0):

When you are building that code for distribution, you'll probably want to put the image into the jar file with the class files.  What I do is put it into the same directory as the class that's accessing it, and then I access it with getClass().getResource(fileName), as in this snippet of code from a textured background border:

```
final Toolkit toolKit  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(textureFileName);
if (imgURL != null)
{
  Image tmpImage = toolKit.createImage(imgURL);
  toolKit.prepareImage(tmpImage, -1, -1, 
            new ImageObserver() {
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image updatedImage, int infoFlags, int x, 
                               int y, int width, int height)
    {
      if ((infoFlags & ImageObserver.ALLBITS) == ImageObserver.ALLBITS)
      {
        int           w               = updatedImage.getWidth(null);
        int           h               = updatedImage.getHeight(null);
        BufferedImage backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, 
                                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
        Graphics2D    g = backgroundImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(updatedImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
        texture = new TexturePaint(backgroundImage, rect);

        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }
  });
}
```